# Are my properties leaking memory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
- (void)viewDidLoad //In this scenario it only gets called once, but in other bits of code with same property initialisation it might be called more than once
{
deleteButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(deleteModelTapped:)]; //Is this leaking?
    self.deleteButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[Configuration getDeleteIconName]];
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *deleteButton;

- (void)dealloc 
{    
    [deleteButton release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Do you have ARC enabled or not? Also, you might want to read up on instruments

Comment: I have tried using Instruments and its so confusing

Comment: Go and find the documentation Apple give on Objective-C memory management. Read it. If you don't understand it, read it again. Find other tutorials explaining it and read them until you understand it. Once you understand it you will realise it isn't really that difficult, but it will save you a LOT of time and effort in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nop,  but write like this maybe better

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.deleteButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(deleteModelTapped:)] autorelease]; 
    self.deleteButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[Configuration getDeleteIconName]];
}
```

the setProperty expand may like this

```
- (void)setProperty:(XXX*)p
{
    if ( property != p )
    {
        [property release];
        property = [p retain];
    }
}
```

the "leak" maybe use "[UIImage imageNamed:]";   :)

Comment: So if this viewDidLoad runs over and over its not going to leak because the property always retains only once?

Comment: don't forget to set your properties nil in viewDidUnload